# Displaying datetime on a chart's x axis and subsequently on a tooltip showing x and y axis value

Tags: c#, sql-server, trend

```
namespace TRSQL
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    private ImageList imagelst;
    public SqlDataReader dr1;
    public Form1()
    {
        imagelst = new ImageList();
        InitializeComponent();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Interval = 1000;
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        timer.Enabled = false;
        button1.PerformClick();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=HIST;database=PLC_DB;uid=sa;password=NCADMIN@123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [PLC_DB].[dbo].[EVEREST] WHERE DATESTR   BETWEEN '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd ") + "' AND '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "'", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr1.Read())
        {
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear();
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.Red;
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(dr1["DATESTR"].ToString(), dr1["Value"].ToString());
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Enabled = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisEnabled.True;
            chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
            //chart1.Update();
            ////chart1.Series.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
            chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 250;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 200;


        }
        con.Close();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }



    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear();
        chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.Clear();
        string selected = comboBox1.Text;
       // label1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=HIST;database=PLC_DB;uid=sa;password=NCADMIN@123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  top (10) * FROM [PLC_DB].[dbo].[EVEREST] WHERE [DATESTR] > DATEADD(HOUR, - " + selected + ", GETDATE())", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr1.Read())
        {

            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(dr1["Tag1"].ToString(), dr1["TagValue1"].ToString());
            chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY(dr1["Tag2"].ToString(), dr1["TagValue2"].ToString());
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Enabled = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisEnabled.True;
            chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart1.Series[1].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
            chart1.Series["Series2"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
            //chart1.Series["Series2"].Label



        }
        con.Close();

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void hScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimePicker1 = new DateTimePicker();
        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
        dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear();
        string selected = comboBox1.Text;
        // label1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=HIST;database=PLC_DB;uid=sa;password=NCADMIN@123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  *  FROM [PLC_DB].[dbo].[TEMP] WHERE [DATESTR] > DATEADD(HOUR, - " + selected + ", GETDATE())", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr1.Read())
        {
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(dr1["Tag"].ToString(), dr1["TagValue"].ToString());
            chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY(dr1["Tag"].ToString(), dr1["TagValue"].ToString());
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Enabled = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisEnabled.True;
            chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart1.Series[1].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 250;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 200;


        }
        con.Close();

    }
}
}
```

I am working on c# windows form where i have to show a trend for sql server data coming in on different date and time. There are two parameters one is DATESTR which is on X-axis and second is Values which is on Y-axis . Tooltip is only showing Y-axis values but unable to show X-axis Values. In chart, it is showing 0 as the value of x axis.